# Restrict one of public api endpoinds for aws ec2 and lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, backend, amazon-vpc

I have my infrastructure on AWS. There is ec2 as a backend server, a lambda that sends requests to this the ec2 backend code on one endpoint called '.../utility'. This '.../utility' endpoint is open to the internet.

So how can I hide '.../utility' endpoint from public access in the internet, but the other backend endpoints left public as they are? And so that lambda can send requests to '.../utility' inside AWS privately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What backend are you using to host your REST API on your EC2 instance?

For example you could if using Go create a function to only allow requests from a specific IP.

```golang
package main

import (
   "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
   "github.com/Ferluci/fast-realip"
)

func realipHandler(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    clientIP := realip.FromRequest(ctx)
    
    if clientIP == IP_YOU_WANT_ONLY {
       // return stuff
    }
    else {
       // 403 Unauthorized
    }
}
```

This concept can be applied to any language or API is written in.

You could also send a header containing a specific token for your API to read. If the request doesn't contain that Header with your specific token in it. Return a 403 Unauthorized